# Apache PIG - Create a new column based on another value

Tags: foreach, apache-pig, valueconverter

I've a column (named Product) that is defined as Chararray that have three values: OT, AT and HP. I want to create a new column and transform this values in integer:

1. OT = 1
2. AT = 2
3. HP = 3

For that I create a foreach statment:

```
REGISTER '/usr/lib/pig/piggybank.jar';

File = load '/user/cloudera/file.csv'  
    USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage(',')
      as (ID:Long, 
          Chain:Int,
          Dept:Int,
          Product_Measure:Chararray,
          Price:Double);


Values = FOREACH File Generate
                            ID,
                                            Chain,
                                            Dept,
                                            ((Chararray)Product_Measure=='OT'?'1':(Chararray)Product_Measure=='AT'?'2':(Chararray)Product_Measure=='HP'?'3':'0') as Product_Measure,
                                            (Price<0.1?0:Price) as Price;

Filter_Values = FILTER Values BY  Price > 0;

DUMP  Filter_Values;
```

If remove the thrid line it works fine, so I think the problem is in when I try to convert the chararray in int.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Values = FOREACH Source Generate
                       ID,
                       Date,
                      ((Chararray)Product == 'OT' ? (int)1 :  (Chararray)Product_Measure == 'AT' ? (int)2 : (Chararray)Product_Measure == 'HP' ? (int)3 : 0) as Product_Value,
                     (Quantity<0?0:Quantity) as Quantity,
                     (Price<0.1?0:Price) as Price;
```

or if you want NULL then

```
 Values = FOREACH Source Generate
                           ID,
                           Date,
                          ((Chararray)Product == 'OT' ? '1' :  (Chararray)Product_Measure == 'AT' ? '2' : (Chararray)Product_Measure == 'HP' ? '3' : 'NULL') as Product_Value,
                         (Quantity<0?0:Quantity) as Quantity,
                         (Price<0.1?0:Price) as Price;
```

Two modification u need to do in your pig script.
1st in place of `=` just put `==`
2nd if u want `null` in value convert it to `chararray` else all replaced value to `int`

Comment: Hi ankur, 

I' still getting error :( I've updated my code